# Item being removed from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a custom post type called `accessories`. When on an post of this custom post type, I'm adding the ID of that post to an `array`. When I'm an a post, a `var_dump($_SESSION['recently_viewed']);` shows the `post ID` in the array, but, when I go back a page, it's removed from the array.

To clarify:

- I access `/accessories`, at this point `$_SESSION['recently_viewed']` is empty as I haven't gone into a post yet.
- I then access `/accessories/post-1` which has the post `id` of 643. A  `var_dump($_SESSION['recently_viewed']);` on the post page returns `array(1) { [0]=> int(643) }`.
- I now go back onto `/accessories` and when I do `var_dump($_SESSION['recently_viewed']);`, it returns `array(0) { }`

Unsure why it's removing it from the array?

**My code:**

```
<?php

session_start();

// array that contains ID
$recently_viewed_array = array();

// store the array in a session variable
$_SESSION['recently_viewed'] = $recently_viewed_array;


// Check if the session variable exists
if(!isset($_SESSION['recently_viewed'])){
  // if it doesn't, create an empty array
  $_SESSION['recently_viewed'] = array();
}

if ( is_singular ( 'accessories' ) ):
  global $post;
  $current_post_id = $post->ID;

  if ( !in_array ($current_post_id, $_SESSION['recently_viewed']) ):
    $_SESSION['recently_viewed'][] = $current_post_id;
  endif;

endif;


var_dump($_SESSION['recently_viewed']);

?>
```

Comment: Because you're always starting with `$recently_viewed_array` set to an empty array, and you're not storing it in the session at all…!?

Comment: OK, now you're storing the array in the session, but you're still *always initialising it to an empty array!* Your logic needs to be: *if and only if the array does not exist at all in the session, initialise it to an empty array.* Then add an item to it. Then display it.

Comment: @deceze - I think I've got it. Just had to remove lines `$recently_viewed_array = array();` and `$_SESSION['recently_viewed'] = $recently_viewed_array;` :) Thanks for the guidance